# angular mqtt update value each receive message

Tags: angular, mqtt

I am using `mqtt protocol` with `websocket`, so I use the browser to display my receive value.
The problem is that I can (in my example) `console.log` the message receive when I execute my function `subscribeNewTopic()` manually but if I receive another message, since I run the function manually I don not get the new message. I'd like to have like a function which console.log the result every time the function receive a new value.... is it possible ?

Here is my angular function :

```
  subscribeNewTopic(): void {
    console.log('inside subscribe new topic')
    this.subscription = this._mqttService.observe(this.topicname).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      this.msg = message;
      console.log('msg: ', message)
      console.log(message.payload.toString())
      this.logMsg('Message: ' + message.payload.toString() + '<br> for topic: ' + message.topic);
    });
    this.logMsg('subscribed to topic: ' + this.topicname)
  }

  logMsg(message): void {
    this.msglog.nativeElement.innerHTML += '<br><hr>' + message;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your code should work just fine. Inside this part of your code:

```
this.subscription = this._mqttService.observe(this.topicname).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      this.msg = message;
      console.log('msg: ', message)
      console.log(message.payload.toString())
      this.logMsg('Message: ' + message.payload.toString() + '<br> for topic: ' + message.topic);
});
```

`this.msg` should have the latest value of your topic.

Maybe you can try to precise a bit more what you mean by "since I run the function manually" if you need more help.
And also try to read to this guild [link](https://bugfender.com/blog/using-mqtt-on-angular-apps/) , it can be helpful.